# Importing pandas_datareader in Spyder (python 3.6)

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6, spyder, pandas-datareader

I'm new in python so forgive me if the question is trivial.
I downloaded Anaconda Navigator and from there I launched Spyder 3.2.8 and then I tried to retrieve financial data from google as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import panda as pd
from pandas_datareader import web
f = web.DataReader("F", 'google', start, end)
```

The problem is that once I run it I get this :

from pandas_datareader import web
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    from pandas_datareader import web

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, can anyone assist me? Thank you in advance ( I'm using Mac Sierra)

Comment: I think you should download `pandas_datareader` package before try using it. And the correct import is `import pandas_datareader as web`

Comment: ok I tried with "conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader" but I obtain this : conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader 
  File "<ipython-input-2-e0d0f13bdcb8>", line 1
    conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I usually install by `pip`, so I don't know how to deal with `conda` properly. Try `pip install pandas-datareader`

Comment: ok it works thank you, but I had to use: `!pip install pandas_datareader` because I'm using Ipython console

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: yes @user1464878

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in anaconda prompt

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation to what this does and why it should be used